# Sqoop hive import from mysql to hive is failing

Tags: hive, sqoop, parquet

I am trying to load a table from mysql to hive using --hive-import in parquet format, We want to do incremental update of hive table. When we try below command. its failing with the error mentioned below. Can anybody please help here.

sqoop job --create users_test_hive -- import --connect 'jdbc:mysql://dbhost/dbname?characterEncoding=utf8&dontTrackOpenResources=true&defaultFetchSize=1000&useCursorFetch=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8' --table users --incremental lastmodified --check-column n_last_updated --username username --password password --merge-key user_id --mysql-delimiters --as-parquetfile --hive-import --warehouse-dir /usr/hive/warehouse/ --hive-table users_test_hive.

**Error while running it.**

16/02/27 21:33:17 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1454936520418_0239_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: parquet.column.ParquetProperties.newColumnWriteStore(Lparquet/schema/MessageType;Lparquet/column/page/PageWriteStore;I)Lparquet/column/ColumnWriteStore;